# When did he come up with the conning scheme?

Tags: plot-explanation, secuestro

In the Spanish 2016 [movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4621630) *Secuestro* (spoilers ahead), the protagonist's (a female lawyer) ex-lover conned her into paying a huge ransom for the alleged participation in killing a man the protagonist suspects to be her son's kidnapper.

What I didn't get from watching it is if her ex-husband planned everything from the very beginning, or came up with the plan only after the lawyer asked him for a help: when exactly did the woman's ex-lover come up with his conning scheme?